# Имя 'Ajax' не существует в текущем контексте

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2019

Следующий код `@using (Ajax.BeginForm("CheckChanging", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "results" }))` вызывает ошибку `CS0103 Имя "Ajax" не существует в текущем контексте.`. В корневой директории проекта существует web.config (но возможно он не подключен, нигде не могу найти инфу по этому поводу), код там следующий:[image: введите сюда описание изображения] .

Через NuGet я загрузил jQuery и Unobtrusive.Ajax. В layout подключены оба скрипта в начале файла. Не могу понять в чем ошибка.

Comment: Что заставляет вас вставлять код картинкой? Почему не текстом? Тут же нет ничего такого специфического, чтобы публиковать именно картинку.

Comment: приму на вооружение;)

Comment: Вставьте код текстом.

Comment: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
   <appSettings>
     <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
 </appSettings>
   <connectionStrings />
   <system.web>
     <!-- Разделы конфигурации ASP.NET -->
   </system.web>
   <system.webServer/>
</configuration>`

Comment: сформатировать его тут я уже не смогу

Answer (score 0):

Мой web config немного старенький но посмотреть думаю можно

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Linq" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
  </appSettings>

  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="BlockViewHandler"/>
      <add name="BlockViewHandler" path="*" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>

  <system.web>
    <compilation>
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего проблема заключается в том, что я использую ASP.NET Core MVC. Насколько я понял - невозможно использовать AJAX вместе с ASP.NET Core MVC, только с ASP.NET Framework.

Answer (score 0):

Ajax можно использовать и MVC Core - я использую, но получается кривовато, хотя, в так называемом скалярном варианте, работает всё нормально. Проблема возникает с передачей экземпляров классов. Я тут задал вопрос (см. по имени ValGer) с проблемой.

Comment: стоило опубликовать это как комментарий, а не ответ. чтобы вам [стали доступны комментарии](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) к чужим сообщениям, надо набрать пятьдесят баллов репутации — это всего пять голосов «за» любой ваш ответ или вопрос